# Why are amidines more basic than amines?

Tags: organic-chemistry, acid-base, amines

Amidines can be thought of as carboxylic acid derivatives with the carbonyl oxygen replaced by a nitrogen and hydrogen atom; amidines exhibit conjugation.

[image: Conjugation in amidine]

Amidines are more basic (less acidic) than amines and amides by a factor of around ${10^{3}}$ and ${10^{12}}$, respectively (from pKas).

I would naturally think that conjugation would **lower the energy level of MO containing the lone pair**; thus, the lone pair would be more bound to the nucleus and less available to deprotonate.

This is an argument similar to explaining why pyridine is less basic than piperidine; $\ce{N}$ is $sp^{3}$ hybridized in piperidine but $sp^{2}$ hybridized in pyridine. Since $sp^{2}$ orbitals have less p character than $sp^{3}$ orbitals (2/3 vs 3/4), the lone pair on $\ce{N}$ in pyridine is at a lower energy level than the lone pair on $\ce{N}$ in piperidien, and pyridine is less basic than pyridine.

[image: Piperidine vs pyridine]

Although I realize that the positive charge on the amidine is stabilized by conjugation (as explored by a [previous post](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/14017/why-are-amidines-so-much-more-basic-than-amides) comparing the basicity of amidines and amides), ***wouldn't my reasoning with MO theory outlined above suggest a lowering*** of the basicity of amidines?

[image: Protonated amidine]

**References**

Clayden, J., Greeves, N., Warren, S. Organic chemistry, 2nd ed.; Oxford University Press: New York, 2012.

Comment: I feel that the stabilization caused by resonance in the conjugate acid of amidine will dominate here, as the canonical structures being generated are equivalent; so this will correspond to a lot of resonance energy being released

Comment: Note that the lone pair that is delocalised in the conjugation is not the lp that is used to accept proton.

Comment: Is that lone pair used to accept the proton because of delocalization in the protonated amidine is only exhibited when the lone pair on the nitrogen with only one H atom deprotonates an acid?

Comment: Related https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/13593/54655

Answer (score 1):

Note that when you are comparing amidines with amines, you are comparing 2 nitrogen atoms with 1 unless you are comparing it with diamines.  Amidines which have 2 ionizable nitrogen atoms are stabilized  by 2 resonant structures, therefore making them more likely to accept protons (that is more basic).  Similarly, guanidine (not to be confused with guanine which is a nucleic base) which has 3 ionizable nitrogen atoms are stabilized by 3 resonant structures thereby making it even more basic. 
For additional reading, check out the basicity of the following drugs.
Betrixaban (which has 1 amidine group)
Pentamidine (which has 2 amidine groups)
Guanethidine (which has 1 guanidine group)
Metformin (a biguanide, that is, having 2 guanidine groups fused together)
Altretamine (which has 3 guanidine groups fused together into a cyclic structure)
Famotidine (which has 1 amidine group and 1 guanidine group).